# Why is my html image scr searching into the url instead of my directory?

Tags: html, image, directory

I have an html file in which I would like to display an image called plot.png with the line `<img src="plot.png" alt="Stock price vs. predictions graph">`. On my website, I only see the alt text, meaning that my image did not load properly. In my command prompt output I see that I have a get request to /mysite/home/AAPL/plot.png, which is extremely frustrating because this means that when I search for the image this code is just placing it in the url (which is localhost../mysite/home/AAPL). I have tried putting plot.png in the same working directory as my html file as well as trying the absolute path to plot.png starting with C:, but nothing seems to get the search out of the url. Please help, thanks!

If it helps, im using Django

Comment: You're viewing this page from localhost, which means it's running on a server instance on your local machine, so `/path/to/my/file` is evaluated within the context of localhost, a la `localhost/path/to/my/file`, not your local filesystem as it would if you loaded the html file via a `file://` protocol. Remember that relative URLs are evaluated based on the current page's URL (hence the "relative" term), so depending on your directory structure, "plot.png" may not (and clearly is not) pointing to what you think it is.

Comment: Open developers tools of your browser and check in the network tab for errors.

Comment: @David I have tried this src="file:///C:/Users/Mason%20Choi/PycharmProjects/market_predict/plot.png" by putting my image in browser and copying that image address but it also does not seem to work. Could you elaborate more on how I can direct my url at my local file system instead of the localhost url with this file://?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the image in the same working directory (in the same folder as your html file) and then use

```
<img src="./plot.png" alt="Stock price vs. predictions graph">
```

The "./" is important as it signals that the image is in the current folder.

You could also use a website like [www.linkpicture.com](http://www.linkpicture.com) to generate a link to host your image and then use that link in your img

Comment: `./plot.png` is the same as `plot.png`

Comment: Hi, I cannot put my image in the same working directory because I want to automatically download images, but the source that I am downloading from only allows me to download to a certain directory, actually 2 parents above the html file. How would I point the url at this directory rather than url, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some web browsers automatically disable images from loading. Fixing this could be as simple as selecting “show all images” from the browser's settings menu. It's also worth checking if the device you're using has security software or extensions that could block images.
Again you can use this tag for .png type photo

```
<img src="exampel.end">
```

//use extension type .end instead of .png

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that I was using the Django framework and the html templates work much differently than regular html files do. In Django you must put the image in a static folder and then call if with Jinja like so: `<img src="{% static 'mysite/image.PNG' %}">`